# Android Studio keep showing The following packages have unmet dependencies:

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, android-studio

am trying to follow the instructions in developer.android website to install android studio in my Backbox 4.10 .

`uname -a` result:

```
Linux backbox 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6
22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

i tried to install these libraries which are required for 64bit:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

but it gives the next result:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.24-17). 
libc6:i386 set to manually
installed. 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that
you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the
unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been
created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may
 help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 lib32z1 : Depends:libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed 
 libncurses5:i386 : PreDepends: libtinfo5:i386 (>= 5.9-3) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libtinfo5:i386 (= 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: libgpm2:i386 but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

==
I tried to use fixbroken and `install -f`. I tried all the methods i know , always there's dependencies and broken packages ...

Comment: `aptitude` has a text based GUI that may help you sort the dependencies. And do you have multi arch enabled? some packages can not have both 64-bit and 32-bit installed at the same time without multiarch